# Why multiple try..catch block not working properly in same method in c# 2.0?

Tags: c#, exception

I am doing this in the `Form_Load()` event of a desktop application

```
string strDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper();

            try
            {
                fnBirthDayReminder();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                if (strDay == "SUNDAY" || strDay == "TUESDAY" || strDay == "THURSDAY")
                {
                    fnAwaitingLeaveApplicationReminder();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                fnLeavePlanRemainder();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            try
            {
                fnContractExpiryRemainder();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            Application.Exit();
```

But the application exists just after the execution of the first `try..catch` block. Even if I place BreakPoint on following try..catch's, these breakpoints were not hit. I am really confused about such mysterious behavior. Please help !

For you all, 
"**if one method throws an exception, the other methods will not run.**" this is the main reason I am using separate try..catch blocks. So that, even if a function gives an exception, the next can execute.

**Edit2**
Can you suggest me a nice approach other than I am using here to execute the next function even if an exception occurred during the first function. The way some of you are suggesting (calling all the functions in a single try block with multiple catch blocks) will not do, that's for sure. I am thinking about recoding the methods without spending more time.

Comment: My eyes hurt, why all these empty catch-blocks and why are you using a DateTime as String??

Comment: Side note: silently swallowing exceptions is almost always a Bad Idea (except maybe in prototype code). Also, executing subsequent steps in separate try-catch blocks only ensures that if you get an exception in an earlier step, further steps are still attempted, probably creating more mayhem, instead of exiting cleanly at the first error.

Comment: There is nothing in the code to indicate why the code behaves like you describe. However, the code as posted follows an anti-pattern, you should not swallow exceptions like this. Instead, fix the reason for why it crashes.

Comment: What exception is thrown? A StackOverflowException cannot be caught.

Comment: Instead of setting breakpoints, what about actively debugging the application? What more information can you tell us about the last line run?

Comment: Is there any static constructors in code?

Comment: I think the code is correct. You could try peppering the code with Console.WriteLine() calls to monitor the execution flow... and especially in the catch blocks, since you're basically swallowing all errors silently.

Comment: Also, please consider this: [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx). Adding prefixes like "fn" to Methods is completely useless, ugly and bad for readability.

Comment: Oops! Little mistake. strDay is used to view the value of DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper(); while debugging. Secondly, I kept empty catch blocks so that even if any exception occurs in the try block, next try..catch should not be affected.

Comment: As like the function names, all functions I listed here use the value of strDay to collect some data from database and then send automatic emails using Outlook profile. There is no problem with the mail sending code as I am getting the mail properly. But after exiting the BirthDayReminder function, it should execute the next method which is not working properly. I have done the debug line-by-line and it does not firing the try nor giving any exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the first catch block, and examining the exception message / stack trace? I've observed sometimes that the application can exit for certain types of exception, e.g. stackoverflow, rather than the expected behaviour.

```
            try
            {
                fnBirthDayReminder();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
```

Finally, your methods shouldn't throw under normal circumstances. Try to find out why they are and remove the bugs.

Comment: I already tried the breakpoint but as I mentioned in earlier comments, no exception is fired. I think a generic exception (like I used "Exception") will be enough to catch any type of exception. If I am right, then it should catch the exception, but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see where it exits?

Answer (score 2):

Using such a code is not recommended. Try to use **one** `try` block and catch the exceptions in multiple `catch` blocks.

```
 try
 {
    fnBirthDayReminder();
    fnLeavePlanRemainder();
    fnContractExpiryRemainder();
    //...
 }
 catch(IOException ex)
 {
    //do something
 }

 //catch(...)

 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    //do something
 }
```

**PS:** in this sample if one method throws an exception, the other methods will not run.

**PS2:** The order of `catch` blocks changed. (Thanks to @ChrisF)

Comment: "if one method throws an exception, the other methods will not run." this is the main reason I am using separate try..catch blocks.

Comment: You should swap the order of your exception handlers and put the general one -  `catch(Exception ex)` - at the end, otherwise it will swallow all the specific exceptions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Put a breakpoint on `Application.Exit();` and watch is it hit after throwing an exception or not.

If breakpoint not hit then your solution is clear. In this case your code throwing a `ThreadException` or `UnhandedException` that force your program to close unexpectedly.

You can catch these exception by doing something like this in your `Program.cs` to avoid your app close unexpectedly:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    try
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        HandleException(e);
    }

static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    HandleException(e.Exception);
}

static void HandleException(Exception ex)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need a finally in there as a try can have multiple catches, but not multiple "trys" within the context of the function.

```
try { myfunc(); }
catch(Exception ex) { doSomething(); }
finally {}
//time for next try
```

Comment: are you suggesting something like try..catch..finally for the first function, then again the same for the next?

Comment: Yes. The finally statement gives a deliniator between try statements (unless I'm really misunderstanding the C# spec :) )

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the standard way of using try-catch block is to use multiple catch block with one try block .....

```
        try
        {
            fnBirthDayReminder();
            if (strDay == "SUNDAY" || strDay == "TUESDAY" || strDay == "THURSDAY")
            {
                fnAwaitingLeaveApplicationReminder();
            }
            fnLeavePlanRemainder();
            fnContractExpiryRemainder();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
        Application.Exit();
```